# Using istringstream like Scanner in Java

Tags: c++, c++11, istringstream

Why doesn't a reference to an object of type `istringstream` retain its last read character position after passing it to one function after another? I'm trying to use it similar to how a `Scanner` object in Java works.

The goal is to create a function that loops through the characters of a string, which contains a signed decimal e.g. `"-14.6"`, and return a signed integer out of it.

For that I use `istringstream` on `std::string`, then I pass the `istringstream` object to one function after another, where each function reads a specific part of the decimal.

The first function reads two `char`s, as white spaces, from the example string `"  -14.6"`, from the `istringstream` object. The problem is that the second function, which should start reading the negative sign, starts reading all over again from the beginning of the string, and the position of the `istringstream` object is not saved.

The code looks like this:

```
void read_whitespace (std::istringstream &ss);
bool read_sign (std::istringstream &ss);
std::string read_digit (std::istringstream& ss);
void convert_string(const std::string& s);

int main() {
  std::string s = "  -14.6";
  convert_string(s);
  return 0;
}

void convert_string (const std::string& s) {
  std::istringstream ss(s);
  bool sign = false; 
  // This function correctly reads the two white spaces
  read_whitespace(ss); 
  // But _here_ ss starts reading again from the beginning of s
  read_sign(ss);  
  read_digit(ss);
}

void read_whitespace (std::istringstream &ss) {
  char c;
  while (ss.get(c)) {
    if (c == ' ') {
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

bool read_sign (std::istringstream &ss) {
  char c;
  while (ss.get(c)) {
    if (c == '-') {
      return false;
    } else { break; }
  } 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The code in your example reads the entire string in `read_whitespace` and nothing in `read_sign` because EOF was reached in `read_whitespace`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added a break if a `char` other than whitespace is read. But still, in the next function, if I print the contents of ss `cout << ss.str()`, it shows the complete string, as if the two whitespaces weren't read already.

Comment: If you exit the loop once something other than a space was read you've already read the `-`. You'd either need to use `ss.putback(c);` to put that character back or use `c = ss.peek()` to look ahead and know when to exit before reading the wrong character. Example: https://ideone.com/AcGpOo

Comment: `ss.str()` isn't a valid way to check what you're reading. The underlying buffer is what `str()` gives you. That's not changed by reading the data. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str You could use `ss.unget()` instead of `ss.putback(c)` too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you. `ss.putback(c)` solved half of the problem but then I had to do anything with the read char after each `get()` to let the buffer bypass it, e.g. printing it to cout, or get is assigned to `char c`. In the code example you printed it to cout. But I wonder if this is the most efficient way to scan a string, char by char, in c++.

Comment: In some cases you have to go character by character. You could skip the whitespace with `ss >> std::ws;` if you wanted to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws but that eats more than spaces and most likely does something very similar to your function internally.